# Why Does Google Maps Fusion Tables Layers Not Load Correctly?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I have been working on creating a map that uses google maps API and Fusion Tables together to create a county overlay over North Dakota as shown below,

([How The map Should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCtxL.png))

The counties are drawn from KML data in a fusion table I have created. The issue is that 90% of the time when you first load the page or when you change one of the parameters in the 'Map Options' Menu that updates the layer, the map renders like one of these following photos. (The dots are a separate layer from a separate fusion table and they work flawlessly. it is the county layer that is having issues)

([Problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Coh78.png))

I know that the data is being loaded because you can still click on the layer where it is not being loaded properly and the functions all still work, it seems that it is just not rendering the img tiles properly. It also loads properly and displays everything properly about 20% of the time, so it seems like my code to shade the polygons is working. It looks like they are loaded in many tiles 256x256 and some of them are bugged pretty badly...(the below photo shows the tile being loaded properly, other times there are parts within the 256x256img missing)

-I can't post more than two photos yet so if you want to see this please let me know.-

It seems like when I add one more constraint to the query to just display one county it works every time. So I am led to believe that it is just having a hard time drawing all the counties at once.

Below Is how I am updating the layer when a new year is selected, or a new species is selected.

---

```
function updateLayerBySpecies(map,layer,locationLayer) 
{
    if(species!='Human_Cases' && species !='Bird_Cases')
    {
    var colors=COLORS; //COLORS is an array of 5 colors
    var minNum= 0;
    var maxNum=50;
    var step= (maxNum-minNum) / colors.length;
    var styles = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<colors.length;i++)
    {   
        var newMin = minNum + step *i;
        styles.push({where:generateWhereYS(newMin,year,species),
                polygonOptions: {fillColor:colors[i],
                fillOpacity: 1,
                strokeColor: '#000000', 
                strokeWeight: 3}}); 
    }
    layer.set('styles',styles);
    layer.setMap(map);
    if(document.getElementById('showLoc').checked==false)
        locationLayer.setMap(null);
    else
    {
        //alert("should be setting the layer next");
        locationLayer.setMap(map);
    }
}
```

---

I don't know if this is a problem with the way I am querying the table or if it is a google side problem. If anyone has any information about this issue or any solutions please let me know. I have tried changing the way the layer options are set and have tried a few other methods but to no avail. This is really disappointing because if it would load properly every time this would be a fantastic way of visualizing the data I have. PLEASE let me know if you have any advice or ideas!

Comment: Here is the 'generateWhereYS' function output being - WHERE WeekOfSummer = 'week' AND Year = 'year' AND 'species' >= 'minNum'-

Comment: I don't have much experience in Fusion Tables, but have you tried check the [Fusion Tables docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer)? There are [several samples](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-fusiontables-simple) that show how to implement Fusion tables. You might have missed something.